# Clear browser local cache by sending http headers?

Tags: cache, http-headers

I have modified js and css files in my website. But browser still fetch the contents from local cache because browser has stored it. I want to fetch the fresh content from the server without clearing the local cache. 
Previously max-age header was set to 1 year. Now I have set it to 0. Still it does not fetch fresh content.

Is there any way I will send headers from server to the browser and it will fetch fresh contents, ignoring previous files stored in local cache.

Thank you

Comment: H2 just push the asset :)

Comment: Please explain me how can I do that ?

Comment: That won’t work - see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Clear-Site-Data`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Clear-Site-Data) header. It is pretty destructive because it removes **all** cached resources, and depending on the value you use for the header it might also clear cookies and other data.

If you use the header like `Clear-SiteData: "cache"` you will clear the cache only.

At the time of writing, the `"cache"` value is only supported in Chrome and Edge.

Answer (score 0):

Send `Cache-control: no-cache` to tell receiving browsers to release a cache entry. This has to be sent for every object in the cache so is probably better done with a script.

Comment: I have added the header . In chromium browser it shows Cache-Control: max-age=0,must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store.  But in Firefox it shows Cache-Control: public,max-age=2678400. I do not want to clear Firefox cache . I want Firefox to fetch fresh content. Although the contents of the files are same,but headers are different

Comment: How are you setting the headers?

Comment: In htaccess I have added Header append Cache-Control : must-revalidate, no-cache,no-store

Comment: Hmm, that should be correct. This is probably a Firefox issue but there is probably a workaround. It looks like Chrome is responding correctly.

Comment: Can I set expire header to older date like Header Set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:05:00 GMT"

Comment: If your headers are correct I think so. It's worth reading up on expiry to get the current best practices as they do change.

Comment: If the browser has cached the contents of files, and there is no instructions for browser to revalidate assets by making an HTTP request to server, then the browser will always serve local version of the asset until it has been expired. To the OP, you need to read how to set HTTP headers that make browsers make a conditional GET request for those files. And before those settings become active, you need to clear the browser cache manually to clear out old caching headers.

Answer (score 0):

If the browser has cached the asset, with an unexpired time, then there is no way to force it to reload the asset. That’s exactly what caching is - an instruction that it is safe to use the asset for that period of time.

You cannot just add the caching headers and expect browsers that have already downloaded that asset to pick up those new headers - they will not download the file while they have a valid cached version! The only exception to this is if the user does a reload (F5 in Chrome) or a force reload (Ctrl+F5 In Chrome).

There are various [cache bursting types and techniques](https://css-tricks.com/strategies-for-cache-busting-css/), which involve changing the reference of the asset (e.g. you update your page from referencing main.css to main_v2.css, or main.css?version=2). This depends on the actually page not being cached. Personally I think that’s a bit of a waste (how many people start at home page, then click on a page, then go back to the home page and require at least a 304 revalidation?) so I prefer to still cache pages but with a short expiry, but that’s another issue.

The answer to all this would seem to be to use the `must-revalidate` header but a successful caching strategy is both about preventing the need to re-download a cacheable asset but also in preventing it even being checked. Those check calls (which result in a “304 Not Modified” response rather than a full download if the file it still the same on the server) do take a good bit of time, especially if there are lots of assets in the page, so using them only solves half the problem - better to cache completely for a given period of time, and then use 304s to revalidate after that time.

A much more interesting cache control option is [stale-while-revalidate](https://www.mnot.net/blog/2014/06/01/chrome_and_stale-while-revalidate), which allows you to, for example, cache an asset for 1 hour, but to reuse it for another 2 hours while the browser revalidates it in the background for next time. This therefore gives a revalidation and update mechanism without the performance penalty of checking in advance each time. However there is no browser support at this time for this (through [Chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=348877) and [Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=995651) have looked at it).

Finally one comment on your question suggests using HTTP/2 to push the new asset. This is nice in theory, but [HTTP/2 push does not work like that](https://jakearchibald.com/2017/h2-push-tougher-than-i-thought/) (though it has been suggested that perhaps it should - precisely for this reason). Instead HTTP/2 push maintains its own “push cache” and then the browser loads items into its “main cache” when needed. But it always checks it’s own “main cache” first and won’t check the “push cache” unless it does not exist in there. So it’s basically a priority order of “main cache”, “push cache”, “server” and the first valid hit is used.